# Make a label editable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application in ASP.Net with Razor MVC4. 
I am displaying text using a model.

My code is

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.UserName)</td>
```

I want to allow the user to edit the user name when he clicks on it. Is there any way to achieve the same?. I googled a lot and some are saying we can use Jquery to do that. 
But I don't want to replace the label, as if the user does not change it then the label should persist. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some Java script plugins to achieve this, and don't try to re invent the wheel -

Try [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: I went through the above link and also implemented it. I am able to achieve it to some extent. But I am stuck with passing parameters to the action in my controller. The action gets invoked, but how do I pass the value of the label that has been changed. Can anyone help in this.

Comment: It would be good to ask this as a separate question, sharing your script part. We are ready to help you. Also please mark this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery as per your research.

I would proceed with something like this:

- At the click on the label replace it with a textbox and accept the user input
- On the onBlur or enter key commit the change to your controller and validate the data (with a $.post for example)
- With the answer from your controller change back your textbox to label with the new value or show the error message